# Парсинг из формата '.cer', для отображения в дальнейшем в браузере

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Знаю что для того что бы распарсить этот тип файла, можно воспользоватся вот этой библиотекой: https://lapo.it/asn1js/
Файл для примера можно скачать вот тут: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byo89V5VmyDrYjdLUDRhS2lGdkE
Смысл в том, что бы извлечь для веб сайта данные с этого формата, например имя, дата регистрации и тд, имел ли кто то с этим дело?